# Русская орфография, или Когда ТС = Ц

Tags: орфография

Я хочу узнать мнение форумчан о возможности замены сочетания согласных ТС на одну-единственную согласную - Ц. Предположим вот такой вариант :
Адвокатский - адвокацкий  
Пиратский - пирацкий
Сотский - соцкий
Советский - совецкий
Готский - гоцкий
Фанатский - фанацкий
Флотский - флоцкий
Детский - децкий
ИмееТСя ли принципиальный и фундаментальный запрет на подобное написание или нет? Примеры, на любой вкус :

> С. М. Соловьев. История России с древнейших времен. Том девятый (1859) В 1641 году Василий Власьев доносил, что он с отрядом своим ходил на **брацких людей** (бурят), Чупчугуев улус погромили, побили людей человек с 30, а живком взять не могли ни одного человека, потому что тунгусы сели в юртах в осаду; Власьев велел толмачу говорить братам и Чепчугую, чтоб они в осаде не сидели, а сдались бы на государево имя...
>
> **Боцман** (нидерл. bootsman) — старший из палубной команды судна...
>
> **Лоцман** (от нидерл. loodsman) — моряк или речник, по квалификации — капитан-судоводитель, хорошо знающий данную береговую обстановку...
>
> Название   Литературный Киров: писатели **Вяцкой земли**, рассказы писателей о своей жизни и творческом труде ...
> Автор   К. М. Войханская
> Издатель    Кировское отделение Волго-Вятское книжное изд-во, 1972
>
> **Вяцкий литератор** ... 2013
>
> Иркутская область 
> Иркуцкий
> **Погода в Иркуцком** 
> Погодные условия. Сейчас Местное время Иркуцкий: 3:39:51    воскресенье, 27 октября 2013

Бывает, встречаются в печати и **буцы** (англ. boots)...
Почему в разных случаях мы с вами пишем то ТС, то Ц, есть ли правило на этот счет?

*Дерзкий grumant*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Согласно основным принципам русской орфографии (фонематическому и морфологическому) фонетическое чередование ТС/Ц на стыке морфем  не отражается на письме. Например, в слове "флотский" корень ФЛОТ и суффикс относительного прилагательного СК, и этот состав морфем важно отразить на письме.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, старожилы форума замешкались, а Вы ничуть)  
Можно поискать и найти *частные примеры*, где на стыке морфем ТС превращается в Ц :  
>Высотский - Высоцкий  
Заболотский - Заболоцкий  
Магнитский - Магницкий  
Смирнитский - Смирницкий

Такое написание фамилий (ч/з Ц вместо ТС) выглядит достаточно симпатично, и смысл мотивирующего корня нисколько не затемняется трансформацией конечного корневого Т.  
Если подобные частные примеры имеются, почему бы не возникнуть другим, тоже пока частным, орфографическим прецедентам?

Comment: Дореволюционное написание : **Кадецкiй корпусъ** (корень - *кадет*)
![Кад. Корп.](http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5625/76558431.7c/0_f1344_310cd0e5_XL.jpg.jpg)
Где же тут основные принципы русской орфографии? Дайте ссылку на авторов и их принципы.